# How can I predict values for the upcoming year based on previous year's trend and a few other variables?

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, linear-regression, prediction

I am trying to predict values for future (2023) based on the trend I have for past few years based on category, month, and size. Essentially I'm trying to fill in the NA values based on past years' trends. I tried fitting a linear model and using predict but this doesn't seem to be working. In particular, predict isn't working, but I'm not sure if this is the approach I should be taking at all.

```
lm.share <- lm(share ~ category + year + month + size + year, df_transposed)
summary(lm.share)
pred.share <- predict(share, newdata = data.frame(year=2024))
```

[image: dataset]

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring potential problems with linear models in time-series data, you simply need to define the remaining variables for predict to use. That means all variables defined in `category + year + month + size` needs to be defined (note you duplicated year in the formula).

```
pred.share <- predict(share, newdata = data.frame(year=2024, month = 'Aug', category = 'A', size = 'small'))
```